# ViewController upon navigate back from previous controller

Tags: ios, xcode

If my setup is:

**View Controller A** => **View Controller B**

Were I to hit the back button on **View Controller B**

Is there a function that gets called on **View Controller A**

Comment: Can you please clear the question ?

Answer (score 1):

Oh ...

`ViewDidAppear` / `ViewWillAppear` ... that was simple

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
-(IBAction)gotopreviousviewControllerButtonAction:(id)sender

 {

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

 }
```